# Search multiple lists by indirective ids

Tags: performance

```
There are x (x=3 in this example) unsorted lists with identificators:

list1        list2             list3
array1[id3], array2[id4,id4a], array3[id1a,id1b]
array1[id4], array2[id3,id3a], array3[id4a,id4b]
array1[id1], array2[id2,id2a], array3[id3a,id3b]
array1[id2], array2[id1,id1a], array3[id2a,id2b]
...
array1[idn], array2[idn,idna], array3[idn,idnb]
```

I want to make pairs: {id1,id1b}, {id2,id2b} and so on. Sadly, i cannot do it directly. That's how it works: take id3 from list1 then find id3 in list2 then take id3a from list2 then find id3a in list3 and finally we got id3b.
It could be done with nested loops but what if there were more lists? Seems to be inefficient. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only better solutions algorithmically would require a different representation. For example, if the lists can be sorted, then searches to get from `key1->key2->key3->value` could all be binary searches. That's probably the easiest and least intrusive solution to implement if you can just slightly change the data representation to be sorted.

If you use a different data structure outright like multiple hash tables, then each search could be constant-time (assuming no collisions). You could even consolidate this all to a single hash table with a 3-part key that maps to a single hash index storing the value.

You could also use BSTs, possibly tries, etc., but all of these algorithmic improvements will hinge on a different data representation.

Any search through an unsorted list is generally going to have to be O(N), since we cannot make any assumptions and are helpless but to potentially search the entire list. With three lists and 3 nested searches, we end up looking at a cubic complexity O(N^3) algorithm (doesn't scale very well).

Without changing the data representation, I think linear-time searches for each unsorted list is as good as you can get (and yes, that could be quite horrible), and you're probably looking at micro-optimizations like multithreading or SIMD.

Comment: Yep, that's my pain in the neck-  requirement of using lists in that case and unsorted sets. I was hoping for silver bullet, some additional hashmap or something. Oh well, thank you.

Comment: If you're allowed to build auxiliary structures on the side provided you don't touch the original data, then you have a very wide range of solutions, and they should pay off (save much more time searching than they take to build) in this kind of really nested search case.

Comment: Another kind of "cheat" you can do if you're not allowed to touch the lists but can touch the keys is to link them together. So like `id1` would have a linked list pointer to `id1a` which points to `id1b`. Then you can immediately get from one key to the next and bypass the searching of list2 and list3.

Comment: I'm doing it (finding all pairs) once per set. Linking keys has to be done by nested loops, don't they?

Comment: It all depends on what info you have over the data in advance. For example, if `id1` is shallow copied in both list1 and list2, then you can, on creating list 2, simply link `id1` to `id1a` as you're creating those lists as you're making those key-pair associations. If you have no control over that stuff, then you have to work more externally. For these kinds of things it's very helpful to list all the constraints you have: what you're allowed to change, what you aren't, the nature/type of the data involved, etc.

Comment: Indeed. I have no control over it.

Comment: In that case, depending on like work/effort/ratio desired, if you're at least allowed to build an external structure to accelerate searches, then you could transfer those lists to arrays, sort them, and get the binary search. Even if the data is changing a lot, if you're doing a healthy number of searches on each one before the lists change, that should give you quite a boost.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to mention that after each iteration i'll get a new set of lists. 
For example, in the first iteration:

```
array1[id1], array2[id2,id2a], array3[id3a,id3b]
array1[id2], array2[id1,id1a], array3[id2a,id2b]`
```

In the second one:

```
array1[id3], array2[id4,id4a], array3[id1a,id1b]
array1[id4], array2[id3,id3a], array3[id4a,id4b]
```

etc. So if I touch the keys to link them together in one iteration I will have to do the same in next one with the new set. It looks like each auxiliary structure has to be rebuilt. is it worthwhile then? No doubt, it depends. But more or less?

Comment: I think it depends on how much searching you're doing per iteration vs. how often the data changes. For example, creating a sorted copy on the side to binary search might sound pretty expensive, but your search algorithm otherwise is O(N^3). So you don't need to be searching that much before things change with a cubic complexity algorithmic for the cost of additional preprocessing on the data to start more than compensating for it.